# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to serialize CPDistributedMessagingCenter

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to Objective-C and would like to know how to go about debugging this problem:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to serialize CPDistributedMessagingCenter userInfo: Property list invalid for format (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFNull')'

What should I look for and how should I fix this?

(This issue stems from a phonegap plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/779)

Comment: What is the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: Using exception breakpoints I was able to pinpoint that is occurs during [productsRequest start];

Comment: (Line 53 of https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager/InAppPurchaseManager.m)

Comment: did you turn off ARC in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was twofold -- first there is an issue with cordova 2.1.0rc2 -- see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1385

Also all instances of JSONString in InAppPurchaseManager.m must be replaced with cdvjk_JSONString